# How do I add text to a file without deleting what is already there?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a login system for my school task and when I try to add text to a Notepad file using Python it deletes what is already there so I can only store the information of one user at a time. Any idea how I can fix this? I've looked around on the internet but I can't find the right combination of words to get the search result I want... thanks in advance. I'm using IDLE (Python 3.2 GUI)

Edit: Problem solved, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open file in append mode, for example:

```
f_obj = open('myfile','a+')
```

Comment: I suggest using context managers instead of assigning the object to a variable like that.

Comment: Well ok, but it's just an example, similar to what docs.python provide

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've added the code and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you have to use "a" mode for appending data in a file.

```
f_obj = open("c:/file_path",'a')
f_obj.write("append")
```

or

```
with open("c:/file_path", "a") as f_obj:
    f_obj.write("append")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'a for append' mode instead of 'r for right' mode, see following:

```
with open('your_exist_file.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('appended_text')
```